# Android App available on Google Play stolen and available other store with different App ID

Tags: android, admob

I received a complain from `admob` regarding an specific App that does not belongs to me, saying that the Ads were disabled on it.

Taking a closer look, I noticed that it is related to an App the I have developed and is available on Google Play, but someone changed it's App ID, and put it on a store called `1mobile.com/` ( Probably a store of illegal  content ).

[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scrapeegames.uphillsmoto) is my original App on Google Play

And [here](http://apk.1mobile.com/mountaineering-moto-apk.html) is the App with a different ID

---

How can someone do this? How can I prevent this from happening? This could causes someone to loose their `admob` account.

Comment: This site is about direct programming questions, so request to seek information elsewhere.

Comment: I'm surprised anyone would even install this. The package name com.oqdfV.oz4gd is obviously randomly generated. That's never a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

> How can someone do this?

What do you mean, download your app, change AndroidManifest and resign it? Well, it's just that. Download, change one file, resign.

> How can I prevent this from happening?

You can use obfuscator and [App Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) but note that anything in your application can be changed, if there is enough motivation for someone to do it. Personally, I learned not to care.

> This could causes someone to loose their admob account.

I don't see how. You won't get any money from the stolen copies, that's for sure. But that't about it.